# Generate Embed Link in Asp.net

Tags: url, relative-path, absolute-path

I want to Generate Embed Link for MultiMedia files in my website, I have two questions:

1) 
how Can I get Absolute Path for server for my files? it returns c:... when I use this Code:

```
Server.MapPath("~")
```

2)
how Can I generate URL s from C# code? should I use \ or / in path ?

thank you so much for helping.